# Finding the frame of reference in which Newton's law of gravitation applies

Tags: general-relativity, newtonian-gravity, reference-frames, inertial-frames, rotation

I've always wondered, in which frame of reference does Newton's law
$$
  \boldsymbol{g} = -\frac{GM}{r^2} \widehat{\boldsymbol{r}}
$$
actually apply?  In general it can't be the one in which the the mass $M$ is not rotating, since otherwise geostationary satellites would fall to earth. So, how is the intended frame of reference rotating with respect to the mass $M$?  I'm looking for an answer that could be used to
make predictions, so simply working backwards from a measured orbital period and Newton's law won't do.

I'm sure that the Einstein Field Equation
$$
   R_{\mu\nu} - \frac{1}{2} R g_{\mu\nu} = \kappa T_{\mu\nu}
$$
is key, since the stress energy tensor $T_{\mu\nu}$ changes if the body starts rotating. (Although this is only the case inside the body; outside it is still zero.) In the book *A Most Incomprehesible Thing* the author derives the Schwarzchild Metric and states that the assumptions include

1. at $r = 0$ there is a non-rotating mass
2. the region of space for which we are solving is empty, so $T_{\mu\nu} = 0$
3. the metric is spherically symmetric
4. the metric is static, i.e. $\partial_{t}g_{\mu\nu} = 0$

I sort of followed the derivation, but my problem is that it doesn't appear to use the non-rotation assumption in (1) .  What he does is to use (2) to show that the Ricci Tensor is zero, turning the EFE into $R_{\mu\nu} = 0$ . Then he uses (3) and (4) to simplify that equation.  This results in

$$
  g_{tt} = 1 - \frac{R_s}{r}\\
  g_{rr} = -\frac{1}{1-\frac{R_s}{r}}\\
  g_{\theta\theta} = -r^2\\
  g_{\phi\phi} = -r^2sin^2\theta\\
$$

Finally he uses Newton's law of gravitation show that $R_s = \frac{2GM}{c^2}$.  However, the fact that the body at $r = 0$ was not rotating was never used.  And it seems like cheating to use Newton's law to solve the EFE when the goal was to demonstrate compatibility between the EFE and Newton's law.

Hopefully my question isn't as confused as I am!

Comment: Hint: How did you deduce that $g_{rt}=0$?

Comment: GR only has local frames of reference, not global ones, so you can't use GR to answer this question. Newtonian mechanics says you can use any intertial frame.

Comment: @Qmechanic the book glosses over that by implicitly assuming that in the solution $g_{\mu\nu}$ has diagonal entries only.  I presume that $g_{rt} = 0$ because $r$ is _defined_ s.t. for light emanating from the centre $dr^2 = dt^2$ (this leaves open how $t$ is defined...).  I guess $dr^2 = dt^2$ isn't true for light emanating from earth in the frame in which earth is not rotating.  Um, am I on the right track...?

Comment: @BenCrowell would the question be more correct if it said "coordinate system" instead of "frame of reference"?

Comment: The newton’s law of gravitation is valid in all initial frames of reference (not taking into account relativistic effects)

Comment: @Aniansh If that is the case my question could be put much more concisely: given knowledge of the location and velocity of all matter in a given coordinate system, how does one determine if that coordinate system is "inertial".  However, I don't think it is the case that a coordinate system can be inertial if there is matter nearby, except locally.

Comment: @AlexZeffertt Just see if the particles in the system exhibit behaviour described by newton’s laws of motion. If they do, the frame of reference is an inertial one and if they don’t, the frame of reference is non inertial.

Comment: @Aniansh.  Are you saying that it is not possible to predict how the system will evolve except by watching it for a while to work out what the "correct" coordinate system is?  Newton's laws leave it ambiguous as to which coordinate system they apply in but that the Einstein Field Equation works in any.  Also, we know that the EFE can produce Newton's law as a limiting case.  This suggests that it will also be able to tell us in which coordinate system Newton's law applies, thus filling in a missing piece of the jigsaw.

Comment: @AlexZeffertt I mean that if you want to determine whether a frame of reference is inertial or not, you start looking for attributes associated with inertial frames(for example validity of newton’s laws of motion). I am sure that there are other examples but this is what I came up with.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74024/discussion-between-alex-zeffertt-and-aniansh).

Comment: Looks like my question has been voted down.  I'm not sure why!  It would be good to know what is wrong with it.

Comment: A frame in which M is not moving has fictitious forces in it due to the rotation. The satellite won't fall out of the sky just because you've moved to a frame in which it appears stationary, because now there are other forces acting on it

Comment: @Triatticus so at what angular velocity of the coordinate system do the fictitious forces disappear?  When considering the Earth Moon system its obviously about $2\pi/24hrs$ but that's not the case with other masses and their satellites.  The question was really about General Relativity and how you use the EFE to answer this.

Comment: The forces only disappear when $\omega = 0$, here for the average human the forces are merely negligible but non-zero. I was just commenting that the phrase was incorrect, hence the comment. I hope someone can answer your actual question

Answer (score 1):

I've been pondering Qmechanic's hint for some time and I now think I have the answer.  (But please provide a better answer if you think I've got this wrong.)

In the derivation of the Schwarzchild metric in *A Most Incomprehesible Thing* it was *assumed* - not deduced - that the off diagonal components in the solution were zero.  It was also assumed that $g_{tt}$ and $g_{rr}$ were functions of $r$ alone.  These assumptions imply that the mass is not rotating with respect to falling bodies, as I will try to demonstrate below:

Newton's 1st law of motion "*in the absence of external forces a body will continue to move in a straight line*" can be expressed in an arbitrary coordinate system with the following tensor equation
$$
\frac{d^2x^{\alpha}}{d\lambda^2} = -\Gamma^{\alpha}_{\beta\gamma}\frac{dx^{\beta}}{d\lambda}\frac{dx^{\gamma}}{d\lambda}
$$

Now, suppose you have a coordinate system $t, r, \theta, \phi$ and a body is falling such that $\frac{d\theta}{d\lambda} = \frac{d\phi}{d\lambda} = 0$, i.e. $t$ and $r$ are changing with $\lambda$ but not $\theta$ or $\phi$.  We can ask the question: will it start turning?  This is equivalent to asking whether $\frac{d\theta^2}{d\lambda^2}$ and $\frac{d\phi^2}{d\lambda^2}$ are non-zero.  Taking the latter as an example, this is equivalent to asking whether
$$
\Gamma^{\phi}_{\beta\gamma}\frac{dx^{\beta}}{d\lambda}\frac{dx^{\gamma}}{d\lambda}
$$

is non-zero.  But since we have already asserted that $\theta$ and $\phi$ are not currently changing with $\lambda$ this implies that one of

$$
\Gamma^{\phi}_{rr}, \Gamma^{\phi}_{tt}, \Gamma^{\phi}_{rt}
$$

is non-zero.  However, these are all zero because the off-diagonal components of $g$ are zero and because $g_{tt}$ and $g_{rr}$ are functions of $r$ alone. (You need the definition of the Christoffel symbol to hand in order to see this.)

Thus, the initial assumptions about the solution $g$ impose a restriction on the coordinate system discussed, namely that in it, any body that is falling with $\theta$ and $\phi$ constant continues to fall with  $\theta$ and $\phi$ constant.

Thanks Qmechanic, you are a great teacher!